# Event listener to determine if clicked target is element of specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to distinguish if the user clicked an element with a certain class (or child element of that class, such as a paragraph), or if the user clicked anywhere else in the page. I use jQuery to see if the event target was an element of the specific class, but this doesn't work for some reason. It doesn't register when the element is clicked. Can you see where the problem is? (look in the browser inspector for console log messages)

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galivan/y15dzskj/)

Here is the code in the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="redsquare"><p>red square</p></div>
<div class="redsquare"><p>red square</p></div>
```

CSS

```
.redsquare {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {

    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('.redsquare') && !$(event.target.parentNode).hasClass('.redsquare')) {

      console.log('target is outside red square');
    } else {
      console.log('target is red square');
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: hasClass shouldn't have start with dot. It should be hasClass(redsquare)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.hasClass()` does not require you to precede the class name with a dot.
Give `.hasClass('redsquare')` a try. You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass).

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu9e5q7s/).

Also, it would be more straightforward to check if element has that class and leave the other case in the else block instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use event.target.className to get class name.

```js
$(function() {

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    if (event.target.className != 'redsquare') {

      console.log('target is outside red square');
    } else {
      console.log('target is red square');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.redsquare {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="redsquare">red square</div>
<div class="redsquare">red square</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

Here is working demo: https://output.jsbin.com/xobafah

https://jsbin.com/xobafah/edit?html,css,js

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="redsquare">red square</div>
<div class="redsquare">red square</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
    {
        var container = $(".redsquare");
        // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
        {
            console.log('target is outside red square');
        }
        else{
            console.log('target is red square');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot in your classname and it will work as expected:

```
$(function() {

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {

    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('redsquare') && !$(event.target.parentNode).hasClass('redsquare')) {

      console.log('target is outside red square');
    } else {
      console.log('target is red square');
    }

  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bzp0ef9k/1/